# QTemporaryFile is empty

Tags: c++, qt, temporary-files

I want to use temporary files in Qt project

I try this code:

```
QTemporaryFile file;
file.open();
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream << content; // content is a QString

qDebug() << file.readAll();
```

But console shows an empty string:

```
""
```

How can I write a string in a `QTemporaryFile`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything is working fine. `QTemporaryFile` always opens as `ReadWrite`, and is a random-access device, which means that after you write data, you either need to close and re-open it (which is an overkill), or go to the beginning of the file to read it:

```
QTemporaryFile file;
file.open();
QTextStream stream(&file);
stream << content; // here you write data into file. 
//Your current position in the file is at it's end, 
//so there is nothing for you to read.
stream.flush();//flush the stream into the file

file.seek(0); //go to the begining

qDebug() << file.readAll(); //read stuff
```

Comment: It's doesn't work :/ I looked directly in the file (located on the temp folder) and it was empty.

Comment: @Intelligide, that's probably because `QTextStream` caches the data. I have updated the answer, add `stream.flush()` to ensure the data goes into the file right away.